# Conditional application of a function (looking for a built-in solution)

Tags: functions

Is there a **built-in function** which will apply a function `f` to `x` when `test` yields true? A typical usage scenario would be the application of some transformation function depending on the options:

```
wrapif[Log, mydata, OptionValue["ReturnLogValues"]]

(*instead of*)

If[TrueQ@OptionValue["ReturnLogValues"], Log@mydata, mydata]
```

It is just a small piece of code to implement, but I need it quite often and wondered why I never found anything built-in. Example implementations:

```
wrapif[f_, x_, True] := f[x];
wrapif[f_, x_, _] := x;
```

Or:

```
wrapif2[f_, x_, test_] := Nest[f, x, Boole[TrueQ@condition]]
```

Comment: Another way would be to have `"Filter" -> Indentity` options and use it like `OptionValue["Filter"] @ mydata`. No you can easily pass `Log` there.

Comment: What about `myData // If[..., Log, Identity]`

Comment: `wrapif3[f_, x_, test_] := Boole[test] f[x]+(1-Boole[test])x` or `wrapif4[f_, x_, test_] := {f, Identity}[[2 - Boole[test]]]@x`?

Comment: ... `wrapif5[f_, x_, test_] :=  First[RotateRight[{ Identity, f}, Boole[test]]]@x`?

Comment: maybe this is not-quite-but-close: ``GeneralUtilities`MapIf[f_ test_]``?

Comment: @Kuba, the postfix-If style seems practical to me, thank you. @kglr `MapIf` is interesting - didn't know about it - but seems to be unwilling to Map at level 0.

Comment: Theo, yo need to use  `GeneralUtilities`MapIf[f_ test_][{#}]&` because it takes lists as input.